# How to cite a reference in another reference?

Tags: citations, writing

I am reading the literature review of an article and the review article mentioned that the second article found positive relationship.

Now, should I cite both or just the second article that found the positive relationship?

Comment: If you don't believe it is a duplicate, then you should clarify why you don't believe so. Otherwise it is apt to be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cite and read the older article that shows the finding. Referencing articles through somebody else's publication should be avoided at all costs. the reason is simple. When you reference a fact through somebody else's work you are also unwittingly citing their interpretation of the original work. There are examples of misconceptions that have been born and carried through many publications because the original have been misinterpreted or misrepresented by a citing author and from which other have sourced the information.

If no other options exist then citing the work as, for exampe " X (yyyy) cited by/in Y (yyyy)" or "(X, yyyy, cited in Y, yyyy)".

Comment: thanks alot for your answer. I read an article in a good journal that mentioned that A negatively influence B based on the theory of Z. when i read the Z theory, there is no direct saying of negative influence. who should i cite here